# Pipe filter based on two or more attributes value in Angular2

Tags: filter, angular

If I have an array of objects like

```
 [
   {name: 'aaa', type: 'A'},
   {name: 'aaa', type: 'B'},
   ....
 ]
```

How can I create a filter using pipe inside ngFor expression, something like

```
*ngFor='let obj of array | filter:name[nameValue]:type[typeValue]
```

Here, `name[nameValue]`  name is a property, `nameValue` is its value.
only show the objects which match the nameValue in name property and typeValue in type property simultaneously.

I Want a more generalized filter which takes any `property[propertyValue]` and can filter output accordingly.

Comment: it is great docs to work with https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a way you could do it. Just give the filter pipe an array of the fields with the values you want to filter it with.

**The Pipe:**

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
    pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(values: Array<any>, args:any[]):any {
        return values.filter((value) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                if (value[args[i][0]] != args[i][1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

**The code in the template:**

```html
  <h3>Only Type A:</h3>
  <div *ngFor="let elm of arr | filter:[['type', 'A']]">
    <span>Name: {{elm.name}}</span> | <span>Type: {{elm.type}}</span>
  </div>

  <h3>Name bbb and Type B:</h3>
  <div *ngFor="let elm of arr | filter:[['type', 'B'], ['name', 'bbb']]">
    <span>Name: {{elm.name}}</span> | <span>Type: {{elm.type}}</span>
  </div>
```

---

> [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IwVavj0tQXQmtpv26n32) for working example

Comment: Just a note: In RC.1 the API has changed to `transform(value, arg1, arg2, arg3)`  instead of `transform(value, args:any[])` (individual args instead of an array)