# Filter one column based on multiple values angular 2

Tags: mongodb, angular, npm, filter

If I have an array of objects like

```
 [
   {name: 'aaa', type: 'A'},
   {name: 'bbb', type: 'B'},
   {name: 'ccc', type: 'A'}
   ....
 ]
```

How can I create a filter in angular, such that when the user selects two names both the names should appear in the table?

```
*ngFor='let obj of array | filter:name[nameValues[]]:type[typeValues[]]
```

Here the name values are an array of objects that can come from the database and if he selects 'aaa' and 'bbb' in the drop down then my array should return name: ['aaa','bbb'] and simultaneously filter the type.

What I found here on stack overflow is something similar but I need multiple filters on one column itself
Please check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736985/pipe-filter-based-on-two-or-more-attributes-value-in-angular2) for reference.

[Pipe filter based on two or more attributes value in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736985/pipe-filter-based-on-two-or-more-attributes-value-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

```
 let selectedObjectArray=[{name: 'aaa', type: 'A'},{name: 'bbb', type: 'B'}]

<input type='text' [(ngModal)]="modal" name="search">

*ngFor='let obj of selectedObjectArray| filterByName:modal]
```

Comment: You also need to make a filter pipe

Comment: Please edit the answer to provide some explanation. Code only answers are not in line with SO guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Want it to work as it does in excel.
I need to select multiple entries from the same column, is it possible?